# How do I connect express to vue app with axios

Tags: typescript, express, vue.js, axios

I am trying to connect my local express api to my Vue app. When I go to "http://localhost:3000/all" in the browser it shows the array "myArr" values as expected. But I can't get Axios to return the array values in my Vue script I keep getting an error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined".

I have been searching for a while with no luck. I have found some threads that provide a solutions dealing with cors, but I haven't been able to get any of those to work.

How do I get the "myArr" values to show up in my vue app?

---

Here is my Express script:

```
const express = require('express');

const myArr = ["one", "two", "three"];

console.log("server is starting");
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000);

app.get("/all", function sendAll(req, res) {
  res.send(myArr);
});
```

Here is my Vue script:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test</p>
    <p class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div
        class="items"
        v-for="(myItem, index) in myItems"
        v-bind:item="myItem"
        v-bind:key="index"
      >
        <p>{{ myItem }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { axios } from "axios";
export default {
  name: "vue-app",
  data() {
    return {
      myItems: [],
      error: ""
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/all");
    this.myItems = res.data;
  }
};
</script>
//style
```

Please let me know if I can provide any more information, I appreciate any/all help :)

Answer (score 2):

Means  value of axios now is **undefined** 
The solution: 
*replace*: `import { axios } from "axios";`   
   *To*:  `import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I don't believe that worked.

Comment: Ah after commenting I got it to work! I think that was one of the issues thanks for you help!